# How to install bcrypt on docker image?

Tags: docker, npm, bcrypt

I am having issue installing bcrypt on my docker.

my node application need bcrypt do encrypt user data. I used `npm install bcrypt --save` to install on my local computer and this seem to be working well. Now I want to dockerize my application.

My Dockerfile look like this.

```
FROM  node:10.12.0
RUN npm install --global node-pre-gyp
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential && apt-get install -y python && npm install

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN whoami

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install nodemon -g --save
RUN npm install 
RUN node -v
RUN npm install bcrypt -g --save
# RUN npm install bcrypt - g --save
# CMD [ 'pm2', 'start', 'app.js' '--log-date-format' "'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z'" ]
CMD [ "nodemon" ]
```

my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Best app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "config": "^2.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "joi": "^14.0.0",
    "joi-objectid": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.4",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
    "stripe": "^6.15.0"
  }
}
```

When I try to build with `docker build .`

This error occurs:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   226 MB
Step 1/12 : FROM node:10.12.0
 ---> a2b9536415c2
Step 2/12 : RUN npm install --global node-pre-gyp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c76403d98dd5
Step 3/12 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential && apt-get install -y python && npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7926c2a74e90
Step 4/12 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5ecb4eb08f05
Step 5/12 : RUN whoami
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e5ff9b23c652
Step 6/12 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d0f9dd01719b
Step 7/12 : COPY . /usr/src/app
 ---> 30d30749e5d4
Removing intermediate container a20cfaca9bb3
Step 8/12 : RUN npm install nodemon -g --save
 ---> Running in a495bc73977f
/usr/local/bin/nodemon -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js

> nodemon@1.18.7 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ nodemon@1.18.7
added 223 packages from 130 contributors in 12.461s
 ---> 9bb36a08bd55
Removing intermediate container a495bc73977f
Step 9/12 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in f544752d8d41
npm WARN api@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 2580 packages in 3.287s
found 1 critical severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
 ---> 5982d518a0e8
Removing intermediate container f544752d8d41
Step 10/12 : RUN node -v
 ---> Running in a08d0492d376
v10.12.0
 ---> c41e54a1910c
Removing intermediate container a08d0492d376
Step 11/12 : RUN npm install bcrypt -g --save
 ---> Running in 874f9d8d7bcf

> bcrypt@3.0.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.2 and node@10.12.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib'
gyp WARN EACCES user "undefined" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/10.12.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-42-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-42-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-07T15_41_19_990Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install bcrypt -g --save' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is working find on my local ubuntu 18.04, but not on docker.
Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Your feed there tells you the problem, `hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib'` so you need to go and sort out the permissions on that directory.

Comment: And another: `stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp'`

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton I am running this as root. What else can I do ?

Comment: You're creating the container with sudo? Or you mean the container user is root? Because the container user (root) will at most only hold the permissions that the docker group and the user running the command grant it. I'd suggest you try chmodding both directories recursively to 777 and see if that fixes it, work back from there to figure it out. If you want to be more in depth try disabling the npm installs and `docker exec -it containername bash` in instead and explore the permissions available in the directories in question.

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton I removed `-g --save` and it working now thanks

Comment: You should post that as an answer :)